# How does gpg handle multiple keys in a keypair?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, digital-signature, public-key, public-key-encryption

As I understand it, keypairs used with gpg generally have more than one associated key: one for signing and one for encryption. How are these multiple keys managed when using gpg (to push to a keyserver, retrieve someone else's key, encrypt, or sign)? Will it automatically use the correct key for the correct action, or is that something the user needs to specify? How is the purpose of each key within a keypair identified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is often called a "GPG key" is more like a *certificate*. Just like in X.509, the certificate contains a lot more information than just the key(s): a 'primary' keypair and multiple 'subkey' keypairs, along with their usage flags and expiry dates, as well as multiple 'user IDs' and 'photo IDs' along with their signatures.

When you upload your "keypair" to a keyserver, you are submitting everything that's public – key, subkeys, user IDs, signatures – as one single certificate. The 'primary' key identifies the entire certificate; its public key hash is the "fingerprint" you see, and the key ID is based on it. Normally, the primary key has "Sign" and "Certify" usage flags, for signing data and other keys respectively.

By default, there is at least one "Encrypt" subkey created, for encrypting data. You can have multiple such subkeys – for example, with different expiry dates. I couldn't find any good source, but it seems that the newest valid (after starting date and not expired/revoked) subkey will be chosen for encryption. When *decrypting* data, all subkeys will be tried.

(You might have noticed that `gpg -k` lists key IDs for *both* keys and subkeys. When you need to force a specific key or subkey to be used, you can give `keyid!` – the (sub)key ID followed by an exclamation mark – to bypass all calculations on which subkey is best.)

Optionally you can add subkeys marked allowed to "Authenticate", which can then be used in protocols such as SSH (via gpg-agent, by extracting the raw RSA keypair) or SSL (implemented by GnuTLS as an alternative to X.509). Which subkeys are used depends on the specific implementation.

You can see the full structure of a PGP certificate by using:

- `gpg --export mykey | gpg -vvv`
- `gpg --export mykey | pgpdump`
- `gpg --export mykey | certtool --pgp-certificate-info`

Comment: This offers a good understanding of the practical reasons behind a master-subkey grouping structure.  However, I am still puzzled by the following restrictions: All the individual keys in a single master&subkey keyset|certificate are obliged to share a single password.   It's terribly inconvenient as the usage of the each key is different and it becomes a security risk for them all to use the same password.  For some keys it is preferable not to use a password, how about that case?

Comment: No, that's never been true technically, and it's no longer enforced in GnuPG 2.1 (due to the migration of secring to gpg-agent, which doesn't even _know_ about key/subkey relationships). You can use the agent command `PASSWD` to encrypt each individual keypair stored there with any password you like.

Comment: And besides that, GnuPG (even 1.x) has always supported "breaking off" specific subkeys, usually the master (certification key), and either storing them on a smartcard (Gnuk) or nowhere at all. So you can very easily have devices which can decrypt but not certify.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the gpg-connect-agent 'PASSWD <keygrip>' /bye, I was not aware and it could be useful.  I'm aware that 'technically' it's been possible even in gpg1.x to set a password for a subkey individually:  lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2013-July/047174.html .  Nevertheless, when considering using 'technical' workaround features using backend methods, testing may have been skimpy, and future compatibility is at risk.  Without documentation, even gnupg.org developers can get confused as whether some behavior is a feature or a bug: https://dev.gnupg.org/T1848 .

Comment: As far as I can tell, in gpg2.1.11, trying to edit any password with --edit-key <sub/key>! / passwd results in all cert passwords being changed to the new one.  So it doesn't seem quite right to say that uniform passwords are no longer enforced. At a minimum, documentation and a run-time warning should be present.  Again, I appreciate the value of your reply.

Comment: 'all cert passwords'  -> 'the passwords of every (sub)key in the relevant cert'

Comment: Old thread, I know, but I'm puzzled by another restriction: That we can [not add a certifying subkey](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234478/a-solution-for-the-absence-of-certifying-subkeys-in-openpgp-certs).  At that link I'm suggesting why we might want to and a hacky way around the problem, though it would be nice if a certifying subkey could actually be included in the certificate.

Comment: @Diagon: I guess this is because subkeys, themselves, have to be "self-certified" by something else (to prevent them from being copypasted into another person's certificate). So ultimately you'd still need to have the primary keypair as the well-defined "root of trust", even if it was possible to have the certification chain longer.

Comment: Well actually subkeys do certify - since there is cross "signing" of master and subkeys.  So they do at least certify one key (the master key).  Why we can't delegate certifying authority by cross-"signing" with a subkey is beyond me.  The question has been asked before.  I gave links.